# Constantly checking for a new tweet

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I'm using Twitter4J and trying to constantly monitor my twitter account for tweets being sent to me. Every time I get a tweet, I want to save what they've said/tweet them back. However, I'm having some issues with this. Here's what I have now:

```
    Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
    //get last 20 mentions
    ResponseList<Status> mentions = twitter.getMentionsTimeline();

    long lastTweetId = 0000L;
    long oldTweetId = 00000000L;



    while (true) {
        //get the most recent tweet
        for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            lastTweetId = mentions.get(i).getId();
        }

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                if (lastTweetId != oldTweetId) {
                System.out.println("recent id is " + lastTweetId + mentions.get(i).getText());
                System.out.println(mentions.get(i).getUser().getScreenName() + " is who we need to reply to");
                oldTweetId = lastTweetId;
                }
            }




        //wait 5 seconds
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
              //Handle exception

       }
    }
```

When I send a new tweet to the account it doesn't seem to pick it up. 
Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Since the stuff is cached, for a certain amount of time, its really smart to just pull once, save the file until cache expires etc and then recall.  You dont want to ping twitter every second or you will get black listed.  The timeframe between updates isnt terrible.

Comment: @Fallenreaper I'll probably change 5 seconds to 60 seconds or something, but I need to keep calling the API to check for new mentions, right?

Comment: There is datetime variable in the pulled down JSON that you would manipulate.  as an alternative, I usually save the XML to a file on the server, and then just run a cron script to update the variable as needed.  Then you just have a defined file you can work with

Comment: Why not use streaming api? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725294/replying-to-users-who-tweets-your-account-using-twitter4j