# Replying to users who tweet my account using Tweepy

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I want to reply to users who tweet me a specific keyword (only when they tweet me) using Tweepy but I'm not sure how to go on about it, most of the examples I've seen use api.search which isn't convenient in this situation:

```
def tweetIt():
    text = tweet.status
    sn = tweet.user.screen_name
    reply_to = tweet.in_reply_to_screen_name

        if reply_to == "myuser":
             if text == "@myuser keyword":
                 # reply to user with an image from a specific folder

tweetIt()

time.sleep(90) # to keep it running
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @dfundako well the code above doesn't actually do anything since there's no connection to the Twitter API, I'm not sure how to go on about it/open a stream without using api.search

Comment: basically this is what I want to do, but with Tweepy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725294/replying-to-users-who-tweets-your-account-using-twitter4j